Truncated Fourier series of Benth and Benth
I am currently working on this paper https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/10566/pm12-05.pdf?sequence=1 of Benth and Benth, and they use a truncated Fourier series to fit the seasonal part of a time series (see page 3). This is given by
\begin{align*}
  d_t=k + \sum_{i=1}^{I_1}a_i \sin \left( 2 i \pi (t-f_i) / T_d \right) +   \sum_{j=1}^{J_1}b_j \cos \left( 2j \pi (t-g_j) /T_d \right).
 \end{align*}
I am wondering if the coefficients $f_i$ and $g_i$ are deterministic so $f_i,g_i \in R$, or what do they stand for? 
I have only found the following definitions so far
\begin{align*}
  d_t=k + \sum_{i=1}^{I_1}a_i \sin \left( 2 i \pi t / T_d \right) +   \sum_{j=1}^{J_1}b_j \cos \left( 2j \pi t /T_d \right).
 \end{align*}
